# MongoDB $orderby and $sort both not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection in following format:

```
{name: "Andy", age: "10"},
{name: "Roy", age: "15"},
{name: "Henry", age: "17"}
```

I want to retrieve all records after sorting their age in ascending order.
**I Tried:**

```
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { age : 1 } } ) //output without sorting
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $search: { age : 1 } } ) //output without sorting
db.collection.find().sort("age": 1) //Error: find..sort is not a function
```

How can I solve this, Thank you.

Comment: what is your monog version

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { age : 1 } } ) 
db.collection.find( { $query: {}, $search: { age : 1 } } ) 
db.collection.find().sort( { age: 1 } )
```